# Why is iterating over fetchall() slower when assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, sqlite

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here (haven't used Python in a while), but why is iterating over fetchall() so much faster than assigning it to a variable?

Eg,

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('dat.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")

def example_1():
    for x in [nm for grp in cursor.fetchall() for nm in grp]:
        # some operation

results = cursor.fetchall()
def example_2():
    for x in [nm for grp in results for nm in grp]:
        # some operation
```

Times:

```
example_1: 0.037526436999999996
example_2: 1.6621453190000002
```

EDIT: The results are the same if the functions are timed in a different order or in isolation.

Comment: Did you also get timing by reversing the calls, so that example 2 is executed before example 1?  Is the time from a profiling tool, or did you use your own code?

Comment: Yes, the results are the same no matter which order the functions executed (or if they are executed in isolation). I used the builtin timeit() function for the results.

Comment: This is aside from the question, but wouldn't a generator expression be more efficient than a list comprehension in both functions, since the list is discarded after the outermost for loop anyway.  A generator expression will perform the same iteration but without the memory and time overhead of completely building a list prior to looping:  `for x in (nm for grp in results for nm in grp)`.  I wonder if the same time difference exists for that construct.

Comment: Yeah, a generator expression would make more sense here. However, it's roughly the same time difference (actually, example_2 takes a bit longer).